# Access control of one page into another page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have two html pages (default.html,index.html) with different controls . is there any possibility to access and bind data to controls of index.html in default.html page using JavaScript.

Comment: Javascript will only work with objects loaded in the DOM, if the next page is not loaded It can't(unless the pages are in tabs in one page only).

Comment: suppose index.html has 10 tabs so its taking long time to load page first time because I am binding data to the controls dynamically. i have decided to bind first 5 tabs in default.html . Is there any possibility